# (C++) Reversing a string using stacks?

Tags: c++, stack, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a string using stacks. It correctly reverses the string, but the for loop crashes when **i** reaches 0. I get a "*string subscript out of range*" error. Currently the for loop only decrements to 1. How can I get it to push and display s1[0]?

This is the main code:

```
#include <cstdlib>     // Provides EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <iostream>    // Provides cin, cout
#include <stack>       // Provides stack
#include <string>      // Provides string
using namespace std;

. . .

string reverse(string & s1) 
{
    stack<char> stk1;
    string::size_type i;

    // this for loop sets the rest of the characters 
    for (i = s1.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        stk1.push(s1[i]);
        cout << stk1.top();
    }

    return "The function was a success. Now that's what I call reverse psychology."; 
}
```

This is the header file:

```
#ifndef MAIN_SAVITCH_STACK1_H
#define MAIN_SAVITCH_STACK1_H
#include <cstdlib> // Provides size_t

namespace main_savitch_7A
{
    template <class Item>
    class stack
    {
    public:
        // TYPEDEFS AND MEMBER CONSTANT -- See Appendix E if this fails to compile.
        typedef std::size_t size_type;
        typedef Item value_type;
        static const size_type CAPACITY = 30;
        // CONSTRUCTOR
        stack( ) { used = 0; }
        // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        void push(const Item& entry);
        void pop( );
        // CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        bool empty( ) const { return (used == 0); }
        size_type size( ) const { return used; }
        Item top( ) const;
    private:
        Item data[CAPACITY];        // Partially filled array 
        size_type used;             // How much of array is being used
    };
}

#include "stack1.template" // Include the implementation.
#endif
```

And this is the stack implementation (a template file):

```
#include <cassert>  // Provides assert

namespace main_savitch_7A
{
    template <class Item>
    const typename stack<Item>::size_type stack<Item>::CAPACITY;

    template <class Item>
    void stack<Item>::push(const Item& entry)
    // Library facilities used: cassert
    {
        assert(size( ) < CAPACITY);
        data[used] = entry;
        ++used;
    }

    template <class Item>
    void stack<Item>::pop( )
    // Library facilities used: cassert
    {
        assert(!empty( ));
        --used;
    }

    template <class Item>
    Item stack<Item>::top( ) const
    // Library facilities used: cassert
    {
        assert(!empty( ));
        return data[used-1];
    }
}
```

I want to change the for loop to this, but it doesn't work:

```
    // this for loop sets the rest of the characters 
    for (i = s1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) // i > -1 doesn't work either 
    {
        stk1.push(s1[i]);
        cout << stk1.top();
    }

    cout << s1[0] << "\n\n";

    return "The function was a success. Now that's what I call reverse psychology."; 
}
```

Comment: it would be interesting to see how s1 is initialized

Comment: s1 is initialized by asking the user for input and then using that input as a parameter for the reverse function, like this:

    cout << reverse(user_input) << endl;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of the following couple of options.

Using the `string::size_type` for the loop counter:

```
string::size_type i;
for (i = s1.size(); i > 0; i--)
{
    stk1.push(s1[i-1]);
    cout << stk1.top();
}
```

or

Using an `int` for the loop counter:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = s1.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    stk1.push(s1[i]);
    cout << stk1.top();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i is unsigned so it wraps around when it is decremented if it is equal to 0. You need to use a signed type for it or to check the boundary condition without involving negative numbers(that is, do not compare it with -1 and do not decrement it if it is 0).